# In java When I enter a number that has 10 zero's I get an error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "10000000000" is the Error I get when I do it. How would I fix it? The code below is what I have.

```
System.out.println("Please enter the first number");
       int MultiplyInt1=kb2.nextInt();
```

Comment: `10000000000` > max int value

Comment: The maximal `int` value is [`2^31 - 1 = 2147483647`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) `< 10000000000` and therefore a `Scanner` will throw an `InputMismatchException`. You may use a `long`, which has a max value of `2^63 - 1`

Comment: What the other comments are actually saying is: each primitive number type in Java has a certain "range" of values it can represent. You want to study those, and keep'em in mind.

Comment: It worked. So now I can continue to code

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this for reference:
[image: Data type and its width]

Answer (score 1):

I would change the data type, in this case you are using `int`; perhaps changing it to a larger type, such as `long` would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing int  with long data type 
System.out.println("please enter the first number");
double multiplyInt1=kb2.next double();